# Flask Redirect to External URL With Parameters

Tags: python, flask, redirect, lti

I'd like to use flask to redirect the user to an external URL with parameters. I've recently came across [this post about redirect and url_for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17057191/redirect-while-passing-arguments) which only works for internal URLs, and [this post that had a similar question about external URLs with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26905306/how-to-redirect-to-an-external-url-with-parameters-and-post-method), but I cannot use HTTP code 307 for the LTI product I'm working on. The solutions in the latter post also didn't include how to pass parameters.

I know that `url_for` accepts arguments, but I cannot use that for an external URL.

I'd like something similar to this:

```
return redirect(f'{redirect_url}?lti_msg={message}&lti_log={log}')
```

where

```
redirect_url = 'https://www.example.com' # external url
lti_msg = 'An example message' # parameter
lti_log = 'An example log message' # parameter
```

Is there a way to pass URL parameters as arguments instead of using f-strings? Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate but see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10765705/build-query-string-using-urlencode-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research and guidance by @Selcuk, I was able to implement it using [`urllib.parse.urlencode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode)

Import:

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode
```

Usage:

```
redirect_baseUrl = 'https://www.example.com' # external url
lti_msg = 'An example message' # parameter
lti_log = 'An example log message' # parameter

parameters = dict(lti_msg=message, lti_log=log)
redirect_url = redirect_baseUrl + ("?" + urlencode(parameters) if parameters else "")
return redirect(redirect_url)
```

<sub>Note: Using the format I had used in the question would cause incomplete data passed when special characters such as `&` are in one of the parameters. `urlencode` perfectly addresses this issue</sub>